# Facing Lint Warning 560: argument no. 3 should be a pointer

Tags: c, lint

When i compiled my program with lint, it is giving lint warning.

```
printf("[Line:%d] at [Func:%s] failed to detect device\n"
                                        , __LINE__, __func__);
```

for this print message, i am getting below error

```
Warning 560: argument no. 3 should be a pointer
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc version 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6) (GCC)

Comment: Maybe it should be `__FUNC__` and not `__func__`?

Comment: Does your lint program know your code is C99? (i.e. what is the program, and how do you invoke it?)

Comment: @AlexLop. - It should be `__func__`. C99 standardized.

Comment: From GCC manual: *"C99 introduced \__func\__, and GCC has provided \__FUNCTION\__ for a long time. Both of these are strings containing the name of the current function (there are slight semantic differences; see the GCC manual). Neither of them is a macro; the preprocessor does not know the name of the current function. They tend to be useful in conjunction with \__FILE\__ and \__LINE\__, though."*. Try `__FUNCTION__`, see if it works.

Comment: @AlexLop. - Suggesting a compiler extension over a lint warning that falsely diagnoses standard compliant code is awful advise. And you know it, or you would have posted it as an answer where it could have received proper feedback.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I know it and I asked it to see the result. If it is the same or not.

Comment: @StoryTeller, Thanks it is working now. __func__ is replaced by __FUNCTION__

Comment: Please tell us exactly which lint program this is and exactly how you are running it.

Comment: @zwol FlexeLint for C/C++ (Unix) Vers. 9.00f, Copyright Gimpel Software 1985-2010

Answer (score 1):

Your original code (with `__func__`) is correct; the lint warning is erroneous.

`__func__` is a feature of "C99", the 1999 revision of the C standard.  I cannot be certain about this, because [FlexeLint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/flex.htm) is ridiculously expensive proprietary software and they don't even allow you to read the full manual for free, but I strongly suspect that it defaults to the older C89 standard.  There should be a command-line option or something that puts it into C99 mode, and in that mode, your original code should be accepted without complaint.